# How to use a Perl global hash

Tags: perl, hash

I'm having a problem with Perl. It's giving me an error that I don't understand.

This is my program

```
our $neighbor = {};

$$neighbor{'a'} = 'b';

print Dumper($vizinho);

sub keyboard{
    my ($a,$b) = @_;
    return 4 if ($a eq $b);
    return 2 if $neighbor{$a}{$b};
    return -1;
}
```

And my error is

```
Variable "%vizinho" is not imported at t/DistStr.t line 30.
Global symbol "%vizinho" requires explicit package name at t/DistStr.t line 30.
Execution of t/DistStr.t aborted due to compilation errors.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 1.
```

What I want to do is

```
use Alinhamento;

$neighbor = ... # Something which will create an hash where
                # $neighbor{$x}{$y} exists if the letter $x is neighbour of $y 

sub keyboard {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    return 4 if ($a eq $b);
    return 2 if $neighbor{$a}{$b};  #And use that $neighbor on that function
    return -1;
}
```

But I don't know how to make that. May I have some advice please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of approaches, depending on specifics that are not apparent in the context provided. Here is one simple approach loosely based on your original posting:

```
use Data::Dumper;

our %neighbor;

$neighbor{'a'}{'b'} = 1;

print Dumper(\%neighbor);

sub keyboard{
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    return  4 if ($a eq $b);
    return  2 if $neighbor{$a}{$b};
    return -1;
}
```

EDIT: Renamed `$vizinho` to `%neighbor`. Thanks @Borodin.

Note `$a` and `$b` are a little special in Perl. See the [documentation for sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).

Comment: *vizinho* is Portuguese for *neighbour*

Comment: Ah, so it was never meant to be a hash reference! Good call

Answer (score 3):

You must start  *every* Perl program with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

and many problems will resolve themselves.

You use package (global) variables in the same way as any other variable. In fact, if you have been used to *not* using `strict`, then *all* of your variables have probably been package variables.

---

**Update**

To set element x, y of your hash so that it *exists* and is *true*, you should write

```
$vizinho->{$x}{$y} = 1;
```

---

Your problem seems to be with how to use references. You declare

```
our $vizinho = {}
```

and then try to assign to it using

```
$$vizinho{'a'} = 'b'
```

which is wrong. You could write

```
${$vizinho}{'a'} = 'b'
```

or, much better

```
$vizinho->{a} = 'b'
```

You also shouldn't ever use `$a` or `$b`. Your code should look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our $vizinho = {};

$vizinho->{a} = 'b';

sub keyboard {
  my ($meu_a, $meu_b) = @_;
  return 4 if $meu_a eq $meu_b;
  return 2 if $vizinho->{$meu_a} eq $meu_b;
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: `$$vizinho{'a'} = 'b'` is correct and equivalent to `$vizinho->{a} = 'b'`, although I discourage the first form.

Answer (score 1):

With the below line you create a scalar to a hash reference:

```
our $neighbor = {};
```

What I suspect you want is just a hash

```
our %neighbor = (
    'foo' => {
        'bar' => 1,
    },
    'biz' => {
        'baz' => 1,
    },
);

sub keyboard {
    my ($key1, $key2) = @_;
    return 4 if ($key1 eq $key2);
    return 2 if $neighbor{$key1}{$key2};  #And use that $neighbor on that function
    return -1;
}
```

Also note that $a and $b are special variables used by perl's sort function, so it's probably best to use another variable name for clarity.

Comment: You're correct in a way, I was careless in setting up my example data structure.  Tiz fixed now.  Thanks